# What is the minimum FR-4 PCB width (not trace width) that can be manufactured?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

The figure below shows a single FR-4 PCB that has narrow "bridges" (marked with arrows). How narrow can these bridges be so the PCB is still structurally sound?

I imagine that the width will depend on the PCB thickness, but none of the PCB manufacturers that I know has this information available online.

Is there a rule of thumb for this dimension, or is it up to each manufacturer?

[image: PCB example]

Comment: Ask your PCB fab.

Comment: "structurally sound" conveys no useful information.  No one can answer a question that has no information.  If you know the torsion, tensile, and/or shear forces being applied to the board, and, of course, the dimensions, the substrate supplier should be able to help.

Comment: Hmm, there was a relevant mikeselectricstuff video, but I can't find it at the moment; it was many years ago. He went into some detail of something he did with snap-together PCBs, with narrow segments milled as snaps or friction tabs. If nothing else, his YT videos are worth binging for manufacturing and teardown topics.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the PCB manufacturer and find out what they can do.

As a wild guess I would imagine 0.10 inches (2.5 mm) would be possible with FR-4. The 90° inside corners should be a radius so the board can be milled out, provide durability, and reduce cost. A 0.03125 inch (0.8 mm) radius is common.